# Spark error when using except on a dataframe with MapType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am seeing the error *Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations when using Spark MapType*.

Below is the sample code I wrote to reproduce it. I understand this is happening because the MapType objects are not hashable but I have an use case where I need to do the following.

```
val schema1 = StructType(Seq(
                 StructField("a", MapType(StringType, StringType, true)),
                 StructField("b", StringType, true)
              ))
val df = spark.read.schema(schema1).json("path")
val filteredDF = df.filter($"b" === "apple")
val otherDF = df.except(filteredDF)
```

Any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: Why not `val filteredDF = df.filter($"b" === "apple")` and `val otherDF = df.filter($"b" !== "apple")` ??